# Postcode Checker Problems - Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript

The idea is that the applicant enters his postcode and if his area is within 10 miles of the locations he is sent to one page.

If not he is directed to another.

The problem I have is that the search box appears on the web page but when search is selected, nothing happens.

Html:

```
// API Key
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBC8nlMS-JbKNcFqF8mTO_cnT5OFqV94Xw&libraries=geometry=false"></Script>

<div class="map">
  <h4>Apply for funding</h4>
  <Br>
  <p>To find out if you are eligible for funding please enter your postcode into the search.</p>
  <div class="search">
  <Br>
    <p>Postcode search</p>
    <input type="text" value="Enter postcode" class="searchField location" title="Apply for funding search">
    <input type="text" value="boosh" style="display:none">
    <input value="search" class="searchButton locationSearch" type="button" title="Apply for funding search">

        </div>
    </div>
  //Above appears to give me search box but if I do not enter the first script line, nothing shows on website
 // Postcode entered but nothing happens
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// locations where eligible

var locations = [{"Address":"Oxfordshire ERF","Lat":"51.925128","Lng":"-1.215956","PostCode":"ox27 7ph"},{"Address":"Thames","Lat":"51.383865","Lng":"-0.138555","PostCode":"cr0 4td"},{"Address":"Devon","Lat":"50.915447","Lng":"-3.332914","PostCode":"ex15 3ep"},{"Address":"Somerset (D)","Lat":"51.080808","Lng":"-2.553969","PostCode":"ba7 7nr"},
{"Address":"Somerset (W)","Lat":"51.18585","Lng":"-2.986303","PostCode":"ta6 4tf"},{"Address":"Derbyshire","Lat":"53.252614","Lng":"-1.328572","PostCode":"s44 5hs"},
{"Address":"Suffolk (M)","Lat":"52.108111","Lng":"1.087697","PostCode":"ip6 0nw"},{"Address":"Cornwall","Lat":"50.425197","Lng":"-4.439917","PostCode":"pl14 3qd"},
{"Address":"Manchester (P)","Lat":"53.579453","Lng":"-2.265505","PostCode":"bl9 8qz"},{"Address":"Kent","Lat":"51.299362","Lng":"1.101955","PostCode":"ct2 0pu"},
{"Address":"Hampshire","Lat":"50.991236","Lng":"-1.534517","PostCode":"so51 6ga"},{"Address":"Dorset","Lat":"50.705269","Lng":"-2.15095","PostCode":"bh20 7pa"},
{"Address":"Wiltshire","Lat":"51.435258","Lng":"-1.981372","PostCode":"sn11 8tf"},{"Address":"Runcorn (ERF)","Lat":"53.331395","Lng":"-2.756128","PostCode":"wa7 4hg"},
{"Address":"Exeter (ERF)","Lat":"50.704251","Lng":"-3.522272","PostCode":"ex2 8qe"},{"Address":"Bolton (ERF)","Lat":"53.566933","Lng":"-2.408110","PostCode":"bl3 2np"},
{"Address":"Cardiff (ERF)","Lat":"51.470867","Lng":"-3.151157","PostCode":"cf24 5en"},{"Address":"Peterborough (ERF)","Lat":"52.575185","Lng":"-0.206181","PostCode":"pe1 5ur"}];

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".searchField.location").focus(function() {
     if($(this).val() == "Enter postcode")
     {
       $(this).val(""); 
     }
  });
  $(".searchField.location").blur(function() {
     if($(this).val() == "")
     {
        $(this).val("Enter postcode");
     }
  });

  $(".locationSearch").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var location = $(".searchField.location").val();
    var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var currentLocation = geo.geocode({'address':location}, function(results, status) ''
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var found = false;
        $.each(locations, function() {
          var lat = parseFloat(this.Lat);
          var lng = parseFloat(this.Lng);
          var storedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
          var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(storedLocation, results[0].geometry.location);
          var distance = distance * 0.000621371192237334;
          if(distance <= 10)
          {
            found = true;
          }
        });
        if(found)

// If eligible go to this page

          window.location.href ="/Funding/Eligible for funding/?postcode=" + location;

        }else

// If no then this page
          window.location.href ="/Funding/Not eligible for funding/?postcode=" + location;

    }
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tested your selectors to see if they work? I would be inclined to put `id` properties rather than css selectors.

Comment: Have you opened your browser console (usually F12) to see if any errors are reported.  It seems you have at least one bit of strange syntax in there for instance: `function(results, status) ''`